# Perl does not receive command line arguments?

Tags: windows, perl

Ive just gotten a new computer at work and Im trying to get perl up and running on it. I have a problem with Perl not reading command line input when I execute the script.

I use Win7 and if I call the script from the command line like this:

```
myscript.pl 1 2 3
```

It does not receive the supplied 1 2 3, but if I call it like this:

```
perl myscript.pl 1 2 3
```

It does.

This first example worked for me before and all of the scripts that we use at work calls perl scripts like that.

```
assoc .pl
```

gives me

```
.pl=Perl
```

and 
    ftype perl

gives me

```
perl=C:\Perl64\Bin\perl.exe "%1" %*
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Prior to this, did you work on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to remove the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.pl
```

It should "reset" the wrong behaviour and make it honour the run settings you have configured.

Comment: Sorry for my slow reply i fix it using another method but your method just helped a colleague :).

Comment: @LinusBrandett how did you fix it? This solution didn't help me.

Comment: Removing `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pl` solved the problem for me